# How can I match my target variable shape to my input shape based on an index/column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, tensor

I am using tensorflow RNNs (LTSM) to train on NetFlow data and have separated the input data into a 3D array with a shape of (1699982, 27, 37), for example. This data was reshaped into time steps based on the individual IP flows and then padded using tensorflows pad_sequences.

I've pulled out the target variables and added them into a list but would like to make them match in a 3D array (1699982, 27,). The only way I've been able to make it work is by using pad_sequences on the target data but then that has unnecessary padding. I've considered using np.concat but then the samples dimensions do not match properly. Anyone know of a good way to accomplish this or is using pad_sequences on the target variable fine?

When padding the target variable, I can successfully run the model.

```
input_data = dataset_df
target_data = input_data.pop('target_var')

grouped_data = input_data.groupby('flow_key')

sequences = []
targets = []

for ip_flow, group in grouped_data:        
    ip_flow_sequence = group.drop('flow_key', axis=1).values  

    sequences.append(ip_flow_sequence)

    target_value = target_data[group.index]    
    targets.append(target_value)

sequences_padded = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequences, dtype='float32', padding='post', maxlen=27)
```

I've run through the entire problem and was intending to make the target variable match based on an index (flow_key), but have only been successful while using pad_sequences.